# Can a telegram bot be linked to a phone number?

Tags: telegram-bot

If one registers a telegram bot, can it be on a phone number? So that the user can text the phone number on Telegram and your bot can answer.

And if it is not on a phone number, how do users then find and text the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram bots cannot be linked to a telephone number.

Telegram bots can only be referenced by their `@username` that is chosen to you at the time of creation by chatting with [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). Users can then find the both by searching for its username and start a conversation with it.

If you want to know more about bots creation you can take a look at [Telegram FAQ](https://www.telegram.org/faq#q-how-do-i-create-a-bot). Also, [Bots: An introduction for developers](https://core.telegram.org/bots) is a good place to start.

Answer (score -1):

Users can find and interact with your bot by searching for it using its `username` or by clicking on a link to your bot. The bot is not associated with a phone number, it is associated with a Telegram account. This means that you will need to have a Telegram account in order to create and manage a bot.

Telegram Bots are special accounts that do not require an additional phone number to set up.
I recommend that you check out official guide to how to create Bots: [Bots: An introduction for developers](https://core.telegram.org/bots)

Some other useful links:

- [Detailed Guide to Bot Features](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features)
- [Full API Reference for Developers](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)
- [Basic Tutorial: From @BotFather to 'Hello World'](https://core.telegram.org/bots/tutorial)
- [Code Examples](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples)